# Golang fsnotify sends multiple events for same file on Windows

Tags: go, inotify

I am writing a simple golang script to monitor Downloads folder on Windows. The idea is that whenever a new file gets downloaded it will be sent to printer. This works mostly as expected. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/howeyc/fsnotify"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    done := make(chan bool)

    // Process events
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case ev := <-watcher.Event:
                log.Println("event:", ev)
                c := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "RawFileToPrinter.exe", ev.Name)
                if err := c.Run(); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
                }

            case err := <-watcher.Error:
                log.Println("error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    err = watcher.Watch("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Hang so program doesn't exit
    <-done

    /* ... do stuff ... */
    watcher.Close()
}
```

Unfortunately I find that multiple events are sent for the same file as shown in the following log:

```
2019/02/11 15:34:26 event: "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\0fcc8a09-9c51-4c5e-a77c-d4f111f6931f.tmp": CREATE
(*fsnotify.FileEvent)(0x10e821c0)("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\0fcc8a09-9c51-4c5e-a77c-d4f111f6931f.tmp": CREATE)
2019/02/11 15:34:37 event: "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\0fcc8a09-9c51-4c5e-a77c-d4f111f6931f.tmp": MODIFY
(*fsnotify.FileEvent)(0x10e821d0)("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\0fcc8a09-9c51-4c5e-a77c-d4f111f6931f.tmp": MODIFY)
2019/02/11 15:34:40 event: "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\0fcc8a09-9c51-4c5e-a77c-d4f111f6931f.tmp": RENAME
(*fsnotify.FileEvent)(0x10e821e0)("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\0fcc8a09-9c51-4c5e-a77c-d4f111f6931f.tmp": RENAME)
2019/02/11 15:34:41 event: "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt.crdownload": RENAME
(*fsnotify.FileEvent)(0x10e821f0)("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt.crdownload": RENAME)
2019/02/11 15:34:42 event: "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt.crdownload": RENAME
(*fsnotify.FileEvent)(0x10e82200)("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt.crdownload": RENAME)
2019/02/11 15:34:44 event: "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt": RENAME
(*fsnotify.FileEvent)(0x10e82210)("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt": RENAME)
2019/02/11 15:34:46 event: "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt": MODIFY
(*fsnotify.FileEvent)(0x10e82220)("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt": MODIFY)
2019/02/11 15:34:47 event: "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt": MODIFY
(*fsnotify.FileEvent)(0x10e82230)("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt": MODIFY)
2019/02/11 15:34:48 event: "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt": MODIFY
(*fsnotify.FileEvent)(0x10e82240)("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Generico-Bill-MULW-132482.txt": MODIFY)
```

This causes same file to be printed multiple times. The exe ignores *.tmp and *.crdownload. Is it possible to get a single event? If not how do I handle this condition?

Comment: If you comment out all the code except `log.Println` in the `case ev := <-watcher.Event:` branch, — does the problem still manifest itself?

Answer (score 1):

First off: `*fsnotify.FileEvent` indicates you are using an old version of the fsnotify package, change your dependency to: `github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify`.

I don't have a Windows machine to test on, so I can't guarantee that this will fix your problem. But looks to me, that the later file modifications are attribute changes.

Watching only the renames to other than *.tmp and *.crdownload should be enough to print your files, since your `RawFileToPrinter.exe` shouldn't care that the file was being downloaded from the internet or whatever attributes are beeing set after finishing your download.